# How can I search through this JS object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, search

So I have this JS object:

```
data = [
{   
    "id": "145",
    "width": "12",
    "length": "20",
    "dealerPrice": "2.46",
    "retailPrice": "3.90"
},
{
    "id": "146",
    "width": "14",
    "length": "22",
    "dealerPrice": "2.46",
    "retailPrice": "3.90"
},
{
    "id": "147",
    "width": "19",
    "length": "25",
    "dealerPrice": "3.32",
    "retailPrice":"5.50"
},
    ...
];
```

My question is, how can I search through this? I found a search algorithm and tried to adapt it to my object, however it only works if I change the property values to characters. So if I change `"id": "145"` to `"id": "foo"` and so on, it works. Why is this? Is there a better way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Search algorithm in question:

```
$("#search-form").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var query = $("#search-form input").val();

$(".product").hide();
$(".product").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id"),
        width = $(this).data("width"),
        length = $(this).data("length");

    if (id.indexOf(query) > -1 || width.indexOf(query) > -1 || length.indexOf(query) > -1) {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
});
```

Full project: https://jsfiddle.net/8toz9xup/

Comment: Your **JsFiddle** has an error in the console. I suggest you look at the and fix it unless that's the reason for your problem?

Comment: How is the submit function you've shown related to your `data` object? It searches HTML element attribute values, not a JS object's properties. If you're trying to use an adapted version of that then please [edit] your question to show what you're actually using. *"it only works if I change the property values to characters"* - In the `data` object shown *all* of the property values are already strings of characters.

Comment: @nnnnnn _"In the data object shown all of the property values are already strings of characters"_ Not at `var id = $(this).data("id")`, jQuery converts the value to a number

Comment: @NewToJS that error was precisely the problem. The call $(this).data('id") and the other data attributes were returning integers, not strings, so the error "indexOf is not a function" was appropriate as you can't perform that function on an integer variable type.

Comment: @guest271314 - But the function shown isn't accessing the `data` object: as I said already it is accessing HTML element attributes. The question title explicitly asks about searching through the JS object, not about searching HTML elements with similar properties.

Comment: @nnnnnn Not accessing HTML element attributes, but accessing result of `jQuery.fn.data()` at `var id = $(this).data("id")`, `jQuery.fn.data()` is an object

Comment: @guest271314 - Yes, where `this` refers to an HTML element and `.data()` retrieves that element's `data-` attributes. That is, the code shown has no connection to the `data` object shown first in the question. (I know the fiddle does use that object to create the elements.)

Comment: @nnnnnn That is not exactly how `jQuery.fn.data()` works. HTML `data-*` attribute is a `DOMString` when getting the value using `HTMLElement.dataset`. `jQuery.fn.data()` can return a plain object, function or any other valid value, for example, a `Number`

Comment: @guest271314 - I know `.data()` does that. That's not my point. Bottom line is the question started out asking one thing and then switched over to be asking about a different thing, with the only connection being in code shown only in the fiddle, not in the question itself).

Comment: @nnnnnn _"Bottom line is the question started out asking one thing and then switched over to be asking about a different thing"_ Not from perspective here. The Question specifically asks about the issue concerning strings and numbers within the text of the original Question at _"however it only works if I change the property values to characters"_

Comment: @guest271314 - I know that. My point, one last time, is that both the question title and everything in the question body before "search algorithm in question" is explicitly talking about searching the JS object shown, not retrieving element attributes. If the OP wanted to ask about using `.data()` to retrieve values from elements they should've done that, we shouldn't have to read code in an off-site resource to see the connection.

Comment: @nnnnnn Agree that the full code should be in the Question itself. OP did ask about using `.data()` to retrieve values, they included that much of the code at the Question. When even the code at Question where `.data()` is tried the issue OP is attempting to describe is clear.

Comment: @BryceRemick See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code at Question attempts to get `.indexOf()` of the number returned by jQuery `$.fn.data()`. You can use `HTMLElement.dataset` to get a `DOMString` value for `data-*` attribute, `.indexOf()` should then match `"foo"` set at property `"id"`

```
$("#search-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var query = $("#search-form input").val();

  $(".product").hide();
  $(".product").each(function() {
    var id = this.dataset.id,
      width = this.dataset.width,
      length = this.dataset.length;

    if (id.indexOf(query) > -1 
      || width.indexOf(query) > -1 
      || length.indexOf(query) > -1) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8toz9xup/1/

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to compare numbers and strings. I just added ".toString()" to the end of your call where you're retrieving the "data" attribute from the HTML element and it's working now.

```js
data = [{
  "id": "145",
  "width": "12",
  "length": "20",
  "dealerPrice": "2.46",
  "retailPrice": "3.90"
}, {
  "id": "146",
  "width": "14",
  "length": "22",
  "dealerPrice": "2.46",
  "retailPrice": "3.90"
}, {
  "id": "147",
  "width": "19",
  "length": "25",
  "dealerPrice": "3.32",
  "retailPrice": "5.50"
}, {
  "id": "148",
  "width": "34",
  "length": "38",
  "dealerPrice": "5.50",
  "retailPrice": "7.90"
}, {
  "id": "149",
  "width": "24",
  "length": "28",
  "dealerPrice": "5.15",
  "retailPrice": "7.59"
}, {
  "id": "150",
  "width": "22",
  "length": "34",
  "dealerPrice": "3.60",
  "retailPrice": "5.50"
}, {
  "id": "151",
  "width": "28",
  "length": "34",
  "dealerPrice": "3.58",
  "retailPrice": "5.50"
}];

var products = "";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var id = data[i].id,
    width = data[i].width,
    length = data[i].length,
    dealerPrice = data[i].dealerPrice,
    retailPrice = data[i].retailPrice;

  //create product cards
  products += "<div class='col-sm-4 product' data-id='" + id + "' data-width='" + width + "' data-length='" + length + "' data-dealerPrice='" + dealerPrice + "' data-retailPrice='" + retailPrice + "'><div class='product-inner text-center'>ID: " + id + "<br />Width: " + width + "<br />Length: " + length + "<br />Dealer Price: " + dealerPrice + "<br />Retail Price: " + retailPrice + "</div></div>";

}

$("#products").html(products);

//on search form submit
$("#search-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var query = $("#search-form input").val();

  $(".product").hide();
  $(".product").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id").toString();
    width = $(this).data("width").toString(),
      length = $(this).data("length").toString();

    if (id.indexOf(query) > -1 || width.indexOf(query) > -1 || length.indexOf(query) > -1) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.product {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product-inner {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  padding: 10px;
}

.product img {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="search">
    <form id="search-form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-9">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Search</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="products">
  </div>
</div>
```